# bind() before connect() may return EADDRNOTAVAIL, even if there's many ephemeral ports available

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

(This has been tested on Centos 6.5 and Centos 7)

If you call bind() before connect() in linux with INADDR_ANY and port of 0 then the ephemeral port that bind() 
chose may conflict with an established connection or a connection in TIME_WAIT and connect() will return EADDRNOTAVAIL. This is with sockets that have SO_REUSEADDR set. 
This does not happen if you call connect() without bind(), because connect() has its 
own (more sophisticated) method of choosing an ephemeral port.

This seems consistent with the discussions here:

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/trafficserver-dev/201210.mbox/%3C001601cda670$fc59e470$f50dad50$@yooser.com%3E

And here:

http://aleccolocco.blogspot.com/2008/11/ephemeral-ports-problem-and-solution.html

I have seen this occur under high load with only a few existing established connections 
to a destination IP, so this isn't really about using all of the available ephemeral ports 
or changing the available ephemeral port ranges.

The simple workaround (as discussed on the apache list) is to simply not call bind() before 
connect(), so that connect()'s more sophisticated ephemeral port selection can be 
used.

But this is not always possible. What if your application optionally allows configuration of an 
explicit port to bind to for outgoing connections, or a pool of IPs?

Any other workarounds?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? If you bind to an explicit port, and the port is not available, and you are not using SO_REUSEADDR/SO_REUSEPORT, then there is nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I don't feel you read my full explanation. SO_REUSEADDR was set, and there were 4 tuples between the client IP and destination IP that were not in use. In fact, only about 10 4tuples between the two IPs were in established state.

Also, I did not bind to an explicit port. I bound to port 0. I didn't explicitly say I was doing that, but I was implying it when discussing ephemeral port selection.

Comment: You did not say here that SO_REUSEADDR was set. You did not say anything here about tuples.  You linked to external sites and expect readers to get facts from there, instead of putting the relevant facts in your question here, where they belong. Also, you did ask here about binding to an explicit port, not to port 0.

Comment: Right. But I did say that ephemeral port selection was happening, so I was not binding to an explicit port.

Either way, SO_REUSEADDR is set on this socket.

Answer (score 0):

> What if your application optionally allows configuration of an explicit port to bind to for outgoing connections, or a pool of IPs?

Bad luck. You can't do anything about it.

`bind()` doesn't know what you're going to connect to, if anything, so it can't take the remote part of a TCP 4-tuple into account when allocating a port number. It also doesn't know what the local IP address is going to be after connection, for the same reason, so it can't take that into account either.